# Can not open "help" with \h or \? in psql on Windows 10. Command "more" is not written corectly, it says

Tags: postgresql, psql

I'm very new to coding and these things so I already have problems with the post-installation phase. I'm using Windows 10 and downloaded PostgreSQL11.

I've already downloaded psql and watched a few tutorials. After the shell demands me to type in my password etc. I pressed " help" and then I pressed "\h". The last command "\h" , the shell doesn't recognize it, and it says something like (I have it in German so it may not be 1:1):

The command "more" is not written correctly or could not be found.

I have already tried to insert the path of my bin folder (C:\Program Files\PostgreSQL\11\bin) into the system variables of my pc. And also inserted the new variable for my lib  (C:\Program Files\PostgreSQL\11\lib). But it still doesn't work.

What can I do to fix it?

Comment: This might be one of the rare cases where a screen shot of your problem would help. If that error message about `more` shows up if you do something _within_ `psql` then try turning off the pager: `\pset pager off`

Comment: Now that i have turned the pager off, it works! Does it have any side effects later on? Or can I just turn it off everytime and then work normally with the shell? But first of all, thanks for the reply :)

Comment: Have you started `psql` or are you in `cmd`? How does the prompt look? If something like `C:\...`, then you are *not* in `psql`. `\h` is a `psql` command.

Comment: I'm in psql. And it doesn't have something like C:\... .  It looks more like "postgres-#" I think i should be in psql, because after i type in "psql" in psql and then type \h it advises me to press \? which I did, but then it shows the error message above "The command "more" ...."